# RUN apt-get update and RUN apt-get install -y \ libldap2-dev not working

Tags: php, docker, ldap

1. RUN apt-get update and
2. RUN apt-get install -y \
   libldap2-dev

both the commands are not working in docker. It's PHP docker image (FROM php:5.6-apache)

I was trying to install ldap in docker container while runtime and in most of the solutions on different blogs got the above commands, but not working. Tried changing the order of command and combing both with && operation, but all in vain. Every time getting this error

### Dockerfile:15

### 13 |
14 |     #RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libldap2-dev -y
15 | >>> RUN apt-get update
16 |     RUN apt-get install -y 
17 |      libldap2-dev -y

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
Please help!!!

Comment: Other questions have indicated that PHP 5.6 is ancient and unsupported, and the `php:5.6` Docker image is built on an ancient and unsupported Debian release.  [How to get and use a debian image that has reached it's end of life while building a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692237/how-to-get-and-use-a-debian-image-that-has-reached-its-end-of-life-while-buildi) is one recent example.  You don't say how exactly it's not working – make sure to include the entire error message – but upgrading to a much newer PHP is probably your best option.